# Can we load any webpage relatively to its link in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to build an Android application. In it, I am having list of links on the android screen, when the link is clicked it opens a new page for the related article webpage in the application. What I want is, I want the webpage to load just below the link. Is it possible?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUJTq.jpg)
For example, in the photo added, we have a list of link to news articles, when I click on any news, a new page opens and on that page, the full article is shown. But I want the article (which I click to open) to open just below the link.
It would be great if anyone can help me in this.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried already?  Can you post an example of what it is supposed to look like when the link is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with a button. For eg:
If someone clicks the link,
open the webpage in this specific webview1.
webview 1 can be below the link/button.

Click on the green tick mark if you think this is correct.
:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a RecyclerView, add WebView to the listitem layout below and make visibility GONE. The make a function to the adapter that will only make VISIBLE the selected item webview and others to GONE. You can get a selected item by adding onClickListener to the listitem. If you need further help, please ask.